# Extended characters [0x80-0xff] screwing grep and sed

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I've got a file that should be 5 variable width column delimited by pipes and some records don't match that pattern.  I've tried using grep to identify these using:

```
grep -nv "^.*|.*|.*|.*|.*$" srcfile.txt
```

but some of my fields have extended characters in them and grep is writing those records out.  I thought the dot expression in the pattern matched any character, but it seems to match only printable characters. In the following example I would expect only the third line to be output by the above grep statement but it is outputting lines 2 and 3:

```
a|b|c|d|e
a|b|c<xa3>|d|e
a|b|c
```

As a work around i've tried to use sed to replace anything between the range x80-xff with spaces but sed doesn't seem to accept the \xAA format for a range. e.g. this works:

```
sed 's/\xa3/ /g' srcfile.txt
```

but this doesn't

```
sed 's/[\x80-\xff]/ /g' srcfile.txt
```

Any help will be very gratefully recieved. I'm using CentOS 6.7.

Thanks, Jim.

Comment: Odd about `grep`. Does this work for you: `tr '\200-\377' ' ' < scrfile.txt`?

Comment: `tr` worked, so thanks for that.  Still curious as to why `grep` does a funny on me.